# Adding Unlimited Form Fields With JQuery Problem

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I'm fairly new to JQuery and I'm trying to add multiple form fields for example, `<li id="container" id="add_field"><input type="text" name="text" value="text" /></li>` but I think my JQuery code is off can some one please help me fix the JQuery code?

Here is the JQuery script.

```
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('li#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                 '<li><input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /></li>' );

    });
});
```

Here is the html code.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="code">Code: </label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="code" id="code"></textarea></li>

            <li id="container" id="add_field"><input type="text" name="text" value="text" /></li>

            <li><label for="comment">Comments: </label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea></li>

            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li></ul>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Your example: `<li id="container" id="add_field">` has 2 ID attributes...this isn't valid HTML, if you made one a class and clarified what you *want* to happen a bit, it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is going to insert your content at the end but **inside** the targeted element. In your example this will result in incorrectly nested `<li>` elements.

In your example I think you're looking for [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) functionality. Each new element will be inserted at the top of the list which might not be preferable.

You can either put in conditional elements to test for placement using [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/), or adjust your HTML and use append.

Perhaps something like this:

```
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;

        if(count == 1) {
            $('#container').after('<li><input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]" type="text" /></li>');
        }
        else {
            $('input[id^=field_]').last().parent('li').after('<li><input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]" type="text" /></li>');
        }
    });
});
```

And as others have mentioned, you have two IDs on `<li id="container" id="add_field">`. You should try to clean that up by either making one a class, or changing your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

you have duplicate attribute for li

```
<li id="container" id="add_field">

<li id="add_field">Add Field</li>
<li id="container"><input type="text" name="text" value="text" /></li
```

>

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're appending list elements inside the existing `li#container` rather than adjacent to it.

A lot of your problems can be solved by adjusting your markup a bit. This will not appear the same as what you have above so you will need to create and/or adjust CSS stylings to achieve your desired look.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('input.dynamic').live('click', function() {
            $(this.parentNode).after(
                $('<p>').append(
                    $('<input>').attr({type: 'text', name: 'fields[]', value: 'text', 'class': 'dynamic'})
                )
            );
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="code">Code: </label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="code" id="code"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><input type="text" class="dynamic" name="fields[]" value="text"/></p>
        <p>
            <label for="comment">Comments: </label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```